# Changing text within a list

Tags: python, list, transformation

I'm attempting to change values in my list of strings.

I want to change these names in my list from **Last, First M** to **First Last** while keeping these as a list type (ie don't transform to a data frame then back to a list.

My current list looks like this.

```
current_list = ["Sanchez, Rick", "Rick, Killer", "Smith, Morty S O L", "Smith, Summer J", "Clockberg Jr., Revolio", "van Womg, Peter", "Lynn-Marie, Sam", "Parker II, Peter"]
```

This is what I want my finished list to look like.

```
transformed_list = ["Rick Sanchez", "Killer Rick", "Morty Smith", "Summer Smith", "Revolio Clockberg", "Peter Womg", "Sam Lynn-Marie", "Peter Parker"]
```

I learned using a lambda function works with dataframes but this won't work because lists don't have an attribute apply to them.

This is what I would have done if the list was a df. I feel like it's something similar but I'm not sure.

```
transformed_list = current_list.apply(
                                        lambda x: x.split()[2] + ", " + x.split()[0] + " " + x.split()[1]
                                        if len(x.split()) == 3
                                        else x.split()[1] + ", " + x.split()[0]
                                     )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension. Split each string at `", "`, then rejoin in reversed (`[::-1]`) order.

```py
[" ".join(n.split(", ")[::-1]) for n in current_list]
```

To get only the first part of the last name, you can do something like this (though then you'd need to treat the "van Womg" separately – I'm not sure if an ad-hoc solution will do the trick across the board).

```py
[" ".join([x.split()[0] for  x in n.split(", ")][::-1]) for n in current_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to assign a key to each part of the list, for instance Sanchez would be 0 and Rick would be 1. Then when assigning your output simply place a -1 on the third (ie. [0,0,-1] ) and that should reverse the order and keep them in the list.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
transformed_list = [x.split()[2] + ", " + x.split()[0] + " " + x.split()[1]
                    if len(x.split()) == 3 else x.split()[1] + ", " + x.split()[0] 
                    for x in current_list]
```

Would this work?

Comment: Hi thanks for for the suggestion @HeyMate,
It sorta worked. the output still has the commas and doesn't remove the extra letters from names.

Output: ['Rick, Sanchez,', 'Killer, Rick,', 'Morty, Smith,', 'J, Smith, Summer', 'Revolio, Clockberg Jr.,', 'Peter, van Womg,', 'Sam, Lynn-Marie,', 'Peter, Parker II,']

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a list comprehension and the inbuilt string.split() method. The split method splits a string around the given characters, you can rejoin them in the order you want.

`[s.split(', ' for s in current_list]`

Will give you a list of lists, where we've changed e.g. `"Sanchez, Rick"` into `['Sanchez', 'Rick']`

We can then iterate over this list in another list comprehension to give us what we want:

```
[' '.join([b, a]) for a, b in [s.split(', ' for s in current_list]]
```

We use the join method to join the two strings `[b, a]` with a space ' ', and we have set a and b to be the strings in our intermediate list.